# DBT view docs button didn't show up after successfully run `dbt docs generate`

Tags: dbt

I am new to DBT and followed the [course](https://courses.getdbt.com/courses/take/fundamentals/lessons) to create models, I run `dbt docs generate` and it passed. But I didn't see the view docs button show up, it was still dark with a question mark. Does anybody know why that happened? I knew it should be very easy but I am so confused why docs wasn't generated with passed codes. Any insights are much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there! Now you have to run `dbt docs serve`

Comment: Thank you Anders! I tried to run ```dbt docs serve```and then run ```dbt docs generate``` but the button still didn't show up... Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using dbt Cloud, not the command line, is that right?

Try deleting your `target/` folder and re-running `dbt docs generate`. If that doesn't work, you can reach out to the support team directly in-app.